# What Thunderbolt 3 docks are backwards compatible with legacy Thunderbolt 2 and Thunderbolt 1 Macs

Tags: thunderbolt

This is the case where you are running an older Mac with a Thunderbolt 1 or 2 port, and you would like to get a dock to add some faster ports like usb 3, but are finding it hard to find an original dock to match the obsolete thunderbolt exactly as in your mac, and you would like to get a newer dock that will work with your next computer too.

So far I have found only one device that mentions back-words compatibility officially and that is the Caldigit Thunderbolt 3 product line.

> "The CalDigit Thunderbolt 3 devices, such as TS3 Plus, TS3, TS3 Lite, T4 Thunderbolt 3 RAID are backward compatible with legacy Thunderbolt 1 and 2 computers."

> "An adapter from Apple is required to convert from Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 2 protocols. A Thunderbolt 2 cable is also required in this setup."

> "This adapter will also enable your legacy Thunderbolt 1 and 2 computers to make use of many functions that Thunderbolt 3 has to offer including a dual extended monitor setup if it is supported by the computer’s GPU. The laptop charging feature however is not implemented in the legacy Thunderbolt computers."

> [Is my CalDigit Thunderbolt 3 device compatible with Apple Thunderbolt 1 and 2 computers?](https://www.caldigit.com/is-my-caldigit-thunderbolt-3-device-compatible-with-apple-thunderbolt-1-and-2-computers/)

There are quite a few affordable used Thunderbolt 3  docks out there, some mention that they are not back-words compatible like some models from Kensington SD5300T, SD5200T, SD2400T saying.

> Only compatible with laptops equipped with Thunderbolt 3 or Thunderbolt 4 ports; not backwards compatible with Thunderbolt 1 or Thunderbolt 2.

> [SD5200T Thunderbolt 3](https://www.kensington.com/p/products/device-docking-connectivity-products/laptop-docks-usb-accessories/sd5200t-thunderbolt-3-40gbps-dual-4k-docking-station-85w-pd-windows-and-mac-1/)

Most don't mention it at all, so does that mean they should work. And for example today I contacted StarTech and their support team noted that it was not possible to go Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 2 saying that thunderbolt is not backwards compatible that way, which is clearly not the case. So for me this looks like a trial done best by doing experiments and reporting what we find. What are we seeing working or not for Thunderbolt 3 docks on older Thunderbolt 2 and Thunderbolt 1 macs?

Comment: I’m not sure we can crowd source a comprehensive list, but we have been very impressed with how well Thunderbolt 2 to 3 allows all working devices to connect to newer macs and newer macs to connect to older devices. This seems more about are the drivers for the device operational on the OS and less about “compatible” for thunderbolt itself not negotiating the various speeds and connectors.

Comment: Ya I will report back what I found I picked up a used startech tb 3 dock, says mac os 10.13 is supported, so in theory it should work, just fine. Just not sure maybe its a TB controller option that can disable backwards support, but it seems like a mystery blackhole of what works or not, so hoping folks can chime in on whats is working for them

Comment: So does this sound like opinion based? or a survey?